# In what circumstances are Database Triggers commonly used?

Tags: database, triggers

In what circumstances are Database Triggers commonly used?

What triggering events are available for use when designing a trigger?

Answer (score 0):

A trigger can include SQL and PL/SQL statements to execute as a unit and can invoke stored procedures. However, procedures and triggers differ in the way that they are invoked. While a procedure is explicitly executed by a user, application, or trigger, one or more triggers are implicitly fired (executed) by Oracle when a triggering INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statement is issued, no matter which user is connected or which application is being used.

Refer [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A57673_01/DOC/server/doc/SCN73/ch15.htm) document from oracle.